# C# LiveCharts adding Target line in Column chart

Tags: c#, wpf, livecharts

i would like to add a target line in Column chart using the LiveCharts library.

I can't find anything on this, someone know how to do this?

here's my code:

XAML

```
    <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Bottom" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Quarter" Labels="{Binding Labels}">
                <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                    <lvc:Separator Step="1" />
                </lvc:Axis.Separator>
            </lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis MinValue="0"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Code-behind

```
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
            {
                Title = "#Bays Needed",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> {10, 50, 39, 50},
            }
        };

        //adding series will update and animate the chart automatically
        SeriesCollection.Add(new ColumnSeries
        {
            Title = "#Tools",
            Values = new ChartValues<double> {11, 56, 42 , 48},
        });

        Labels = new[] {"Q1Y23", "Q2Y23", "Q3Y23", "Q4Y23"};
```